# Mute music being played by Rythm.js when mouse is not on an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mute

I am using [Rythm.js](https://github.com/Okazari/Rythm.js) to get an element to 'dance' in time to a song. (The element a paper created using Raphiel.js but I think that's besides the point.)

I then need the song to mute when the mouse is not on a specific element. The specific element is different form the HTML element.

This is the code that starts the song playing:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
audio.loop = true;
audio.play();
```

Also this is the code that I intend to use to mute the audio:

```
$(function() {
    $('main').hover(function() {
        audio.muted = false;
    }, function() {
        audio.muted = true;
    });
});
```

And this is the code that initializes Rythm.js:

```
var rythm = new Rythm();
rythm.setMusic("brighton.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rythm.connectExternalAudioElement(audioElement)` to connect your own element. Otherwise rythm will act as a player and create his own audio element.

Feel free to ask if you want more information.